# How to edit the Amcharts X Axis?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, amcharts

I'm using the [Amcharts](https://www.amcharts.com/) in a react application using the following lib
[amcharts3-react](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts3-react).

This is my Amcharts config:

```
export const arabicCharts = {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "autoMarginOffset": 20,
  "graphs": [{
    "id": "g1",
    "balloonText": "[[value]]",
    "bullet": "diamond",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "hideBulletsCount": 50,
    "title": "red line",
    "valueField": "ay",
    "lineAlpha": 0.8,
    "lineThickness": 2,
    "lineColor": "#b0de09",
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true
  }, {
    "id": "g2",
    "balloonText": "[[value]]",
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "hideBulletsCount": 50,
    "title": "red line",
    "valueField": "by",
    "lineAlpha": 0.8,
    "lineThickness": 2,
    "lineColor": "#fcd202",
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true
  }],
  "chartCursor": {
    "limitToGraph": "g1"
  },
  "categoryField": "date",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true,
    "axisColor": "#DADADA",
    "dashLength": 1,
    "minorGridEnabled": true
  },
  "valueAxes": [{
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "position": "right",
  },{
    "axisAlpha": 1,
    "position": "bottom",
  }],
};
```

valueAxes is only applied for the Y Axis by adding his title.

Why is not applied for the X Axis? valueAxes second object is not working.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already answered on Github, but for anyone else that's curious (note that this relates to AmCharts 3):

Serial charts in AmCharts 3 can only have one horizontal/X axis (or Y if `rotate: true` is set), and that axis must be a category axis, which isn't fully numeric. You can set the second value axis as a second Y axis (`position: "left"` or `position: "right"`), but you also need to specify IDs and assign your graphs to them, e.g.

```
graphs: [{
  // ...
  "valueAxis": "v1, //use right hand axis
}, {
  // ...
  valueAxis: "v2" //use left hand axis
}],
// ...
valueAxes: [{
  "position": "right",
  "id": "v1",
  // ...
}, {
  "position": "left",
  "id": "v2"
}]
```

If you need both a numeric X and Y axis, consider using v3's XY chart instead.